# Twitter bootstrap table with jquery animations

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have the following markup with twitter bootstrap

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Example </th>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I animate the row using jquery's `slideUp()` function to remove it, while keeping the twitter bootstrap styling, given that `<tr>`s really don't animate well. If I switch to `div`'s, I can't use the `table` class from bootstrap any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand your question but check out this example.  Let me know if it doesn't address your question.

jQuery

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    $('.table td:first').slideUp();
});
```

Html included in example link

http://www.bootply.com/91188

**Update**

1. This hides the input so that it does not get caught when sliding up (stops the judders)
   http://www.bootply.com/91216
2. This slides up the div first and then as soon as that has finished it will slide up the row.
   http://www.bootply.com/91214

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, in my actual table there are many columns, so I can't do `.table td:first`, but I may be able to do `.table td`. To make progress I used divs and styled them to look like a table. Not sure this is ideal from a html-should-describe-structure-not-style point of view, but it works :)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure all browsers will do the animation correctly (the example at bootply in chrome judders and then jumps up)

Comment: @derekdreery Yeah that's because its running into the input.  I'll add two more links with additional examples that may be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort :)